# Clickable link on animated object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have an issue with an animated baloon. I would like to have the whole baloon clickable as the mouse pointer is over the baloon. Currently only the bottom portion of the ballon is clickable and turn into a pointer cursor as the mouse is hovering over the ballon. Could anybody see what I am doing wrong in the code below?

Baloon on the index page:

```
<a href="contactus.html"><div style="cursor: pointer;" class="baloon"></div></a>
```

CSS file:

```
.baloon {
  width:375px;
  height:490px;
  background:url('../images/balloon.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-left: 435px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  z-index: 90;
}
```

The baloon is animated with jQuery up and down. (can post more of the animation code is required)

Comment: what's your style for <a/> tag?

Comment: You need to correct your mark-up first. It should be `div style="cursor: pointer;" class="baloon"></div>` :)

Comment: Also instead of having a block element instead of an inline element, I suggest you change your `div` to some inline element like `<span>` or even all your styles to the `a` (anchor) element itself.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I meant to say block element(div) `inside` of an inline element (a).

Comment: Style for a:

a {
 color: #6495ED;
 text-decoration: none;
}